# What is the default hashing algorithm used by Django cache

Tags: python, django, caching

I am using caching in Django. My cache is a django-redis cache:

```
CACHES = {
    "default": {
        "BACKEND": "django_redis.cache.RedisCache",
        "LOCATION": "redis://127.0.0.1:6379",
        "OPTIONS": {
            "CLIENT_CLASS": "django_redis.client.DefaultClient",
        }
    }
}
```

I am using view based cache:

```
@cache_page(timeout=60 * 10)
def my_view(request: Request):
  # my view stuff
```

What I would like to know is what is the algorithm used by Django to create the key? The docs just say that it's made from the URL and headers. But I would like to know the specifics or better yet the code that generates it. But the docs lack this information.

So, how does Django derive keys for view based caches?

Answer (score 1):

Found it!

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/_modules/django/utils/cache/

What you are looking for is the method `_generate_cache_header_key`. Below is how it looks like as of writing this answer:

```
def _generate_cache_header_key(key_prefix, request):
    """Return a cache key for the header cache."""
    url = hashlib.md5(force_bytes(iri_to_uri(request.build_absolute_uri())))
    cache_key = 'views.decorators.cache.cache_header.%s.%s' % (
        key_prefix, url.hexdigest())
    return _i18n_cache_key_suffix(request, cache_key)
```